# Connect Oracle12c using python(Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804)

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, oracle12c

I have tried to connect oracle12c database using python, below are the steps which I performed:

1. Installed cx_Oracle on anaconda prompt.

   `pip install cx_Oracle`
2. below is the code which I wrote in python script.

   ````py
   import cx_Oracle
   dsnStr = cx_Oracle.makedsn("192.168.1.92", "1521", "orcl")
   con = cx_Oracle.connect(user="xxxxx", password="xxxxx", dsn=dsnStr)```
   ````

after running above commands in Spyder, I am getting below error:

> DatabaseError: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804

Oracle and PostgreSQL, both are installed on Windows 10 Machine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> There are several causes for the ORA-01804 error:
>
> - Check to make sure the following paths are set correctly in your environment:
>
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH  ORACLE_HOME  NLS_LANG
>
> - Your oracle client may be missing some timezone dat files in the $ORACLE_HOME directory. You should have a separate ORACLE_HOME for
>     each release of Oracle.
> - Check that the permissions are set to allow reads (chmod 444) for the files in the OCCI library.

[Source](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01804_start_oracle.htm)

Comment: what is LD_LIBRARY_PATH and NLS_LANG ? and how to set it?

Comment: sorry I wrote the answer before your update regarding windows, I do not have any Idea how to set them on windows